# The For Loop Initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, loops, for-loop

So I was wondering whether I could declare a variable in the declaration of a for loop. Would this code be valid?

```
for (int a = 0;a < len + 1;a++);
```

In what scope would `a` exist in? Would it be invalid outside the for loop, or would I still be able to access it?

Also, is it possible for me to declare or initialize 2 variables in a single for loop statement?

```
for (int a = 0, b = len + 1;a < b;a++);
```

Is this a valid statement?

Comment: firstly, did you try it? well Clearly you didn't otherwise you would have your answers.,.

Comment: Answers have specified that the multi-variable initializer is valid, and they are correct. You should know, however, that they are only so because they're of the same type. (i.e. they're both `int`). You cannot split var-decls of different types in a for-initializer (and you do not, so this is perfectly fine).

Comment: -1: Clearly no research. Your C++ book covers the way in which `for` loops work. Plus you could have tried it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are perfectly valid because the initialisation part of the `for` statement (known as the *for-init-statement*) is either an *expression-statement* or a *simple-declaration*. Both of your examples are *simple-declarations* - the second just has two declarators.

The scope of variables declared in a *for-init-statement* is the `for` loop itself, so it is not available outside the `for` loop (§6.5.3/3):

> If the *for-init-statement* is a declaration, the scope of the name(s) declared extends to the end of the *for-statement*.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare then inside of the for loop and is the normal method of doing so.

Normally its scope is as long as the {} of the for loop.

Visual Studio (not sure about other compilers) can set flags to extend the scope outside of the for loop.  Don't do that though.

You can declare multiple variables in the for loop initialization, as long as they are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

It would be invalid outside the `for` loop because it’s scoped to the `for` loop, yes. And yes, that’s also a valid declaration.

[Working](http://codepad.org/fcqnQtf8) and [not working](http://codepad.org/LafVcZg9).

Answer (score 1):

both are valid, but in this case:

```
for (int a = 0, b = len + 1;a < b;++a);
```

will be faster that

```
for (int a = 0;a < len + 1;++a);
```

because len+1 is pre-calculated.

Comment: Any decent optimising compiler will generate code for those two loops that runs at exactly the same speed. Optimise for readability, not for what you think the compiler will do with your code.

Comment: @GregHewgill: ... assuming that compiler can determine that `len` is not changed during the execution of the loop's body.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: True, in most cases this will be possible (unless `len` is global, for example).

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int a = 0;a < len + 1;a++);
```

this is perfectly fine if "int i" is not declared before this statement.

One can't access "a" outside for loop.

```
for (int a = 0, b = len + 1;a < b;a++);
```

this is also fine but

```
for (int a = 0;int b = len + 1;a < b;a++);
```

OR

```
for (int a = 0;double b = len + 1;a < b;a++);
```

both of above statement are not valid b'se you have to replace "comma" by "semicolon" and